# Should I learn the four conjugations?

Tags: conjugation

So I did well in my Latin GCSE this year  but we just learned that -o is first person, -s is second person, etc. But I had a closer look at the textbook today and it lists verbs in four conjugations types. Eg. porto is first, doceo is second, traho is third and audio is fourth.

Do I need to learn which type a verb is? How important is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

For a simple example, "I will love" is *amā-bō*, while "I will hear" is *audī-am*. Why does one take *-bō* and the other take *-am*? It depends which conjugation they're in; 1 and 2 use *-bō*, while 3 and 4 use *-am*.

Once you get out of the "present system" (present, imperfect, future), things get even more complicated. You'll want to learn the four *principal parts* for each verb: a set of four specific forms that let you derive all the others. For "run", for example, these forms are *currō, currere, cucurrī, cursus*, and there's unfortunately no reliable way to derive any of those from any other—you simply have to know all four.

Comment: Thanks! Useful answer. So it would matter if I wanted to compose Latin, but would it matter in terms of translation into English?

Comment: Although audī-am is a reasonable representation of the underlying structure, presenting the form that way might obscure the fact that the actual surface form scans with short i because of the rule of shortening vowels in hiatus.

Comment: @Asteroides Very true.

Comment: @TomHahn Absolutely. For example, _habet_ is present but _curret_ is future (present would be _currit_); _amat_ is indicative but _dicat_ is subjunctive (indicative would be _dicit_). These distinctions are lost if you don't know the conjugations.

Comment: @Draconis Thanks. One more thing, if you know the present form/infinitive can you tell which conjugation they are in, or do you just learn them with the new vocabulary?

Comment: @TomHahn The infinitive tells you the conjugation. (That's the main reason it's included as a principal part; the reason you need the first singular also is for an edge case involving the third conjugation.)

Comment: @Draconis Great. Thanks so much!

Comment: You'll find you don't have to learn every form of every conjugation independently. For example, the present indicative of all conjugations has the same pattern, just with a change in vowel. And once you know the perfect stem (the third "principle part") forming the perfect (and the derived tenses) have identical endings for every verb.

Comment: If you memorise infinitives, it is important to notice the length of the *e* before *-re*: short *e* (often written as ĕ) indicates a consonantal stem, while long *e* (often written as ē) indicates an e-stem.